# What it takes to turn an app into SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I was just wondering what it takes to turn an already existing part of an app (let's say one activity and several fragments) into an SDK that can be used in different apps.

What should be done and how much time approximately will it take.

PS: I haven't created any SDK previously I only have experience with building apps and using already created SDKs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert an app module to a library module

If you have an existing app module with all the code you want to reuse, you can turn it into a library module as follows:

1. Open the module-level **build.gradle** file.
2. Delete the line for the `applicationId`. Only an Android app module
   can define this.
3. At the top of the file, you should see the following:

   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Change it to the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Save the file and click **Tools > Android > Sync Project with Gradle Files**.
That's it.

The entire structure of the module remains the same, but it now operates as an Android library and the build will now create an AAR file instead of an APK.

When you want to build the AAR file, select the library module in the Project window and then click Build > Build APK.

[Official Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

Comment: @MohammadHaidar let me know if you have anything missing from puzzle.